# class object assignment - c++

Tags: c++

I have a class 'Record' as follows:

```
class Record {

private:
    char *bits;
    char* GetBits ();
    void SetBits (char *bits);
    void CopyBits(char *bits, int b_len);

public:
    Record ();
    ~Record();
}
```

I have an array of Record objects as follows:

```
Record *recBuffer = new (std::nothrow)Record[RECORD_SIZE];
```

Assume that the recBuffer has been filled with values. When I print them, they are fine. What could be the problem with the following code?

```
 Record *newPtr = new (std::nothrow) Record[2*RECORD_SIZE];
 if (NULL == newPtr) {
     return;
 }

 //copy everything
 for (int i = 0; i < RECORD_SIZE; i++) {
     newPtr[i] = recBuffer[i];
 }

 delete[] recBuffer;
 recBuffer = newPtr;
```

When I try printing the values of recBuffer till RECORD_SIZE, the first few values are corrupted and then there is a segfault finally!

So, I am updating the post with an answer by Ben:
So, if you copy a Record (copying the bits pointer), (newPtr[i] = recBuffer[i]) they both will call delete[] with the same pointer. See a problem?

Comment: Who owns the buffer pointed-to by `Record::bits`?  Most likely you are keeping a pointer after the buffer is freed.

Comment: Show the implementation of the `Record` member functions, especially including the constructor and destructor.

Comment: Who is forcing you to use a clearly broken class?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: we are trying to build a database. we have some classes given to us, on which we need to build further. it might be broken, or not a very good class but the functionality provided is very useful and speeds up the work.

Comment: Ridiculous.  Whoever wrote the above class could not possibly have produced anything useful.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: That's not true, they might have plenty of domain knowledge.  What is true is that they certainly weren't knowledgeable about C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're violating the "Rule of Five": If you have any of the following, you probably need to write all the other four:

- user-defined copy constructor
- user-defined move constructor
- user-defined assignment operator
- user-defined move assignment operator
- user-defined destructor

See:

- [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)
- [Rule-of-Three becomes Rule-of-Five with C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11)
- [How to actually implement the rule of five?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976459/how-to-actually-implement-the-rule-of-five)

---

Dynamic arrays are used so much that someone has already done all this hard work.  Just change `bits` to a `std::vector<char>` and all the compiler-generated special member functions will just do the right thing.  If `bits` points to memory owned by the `Record` object.  If you're intending to share memory between many objects, you can consider `shared_ptr` as suggested by Seth in the comments.  But I suspect you aren't wanting any sharing.

Comment: Or use `std::shared_ptr` if you want to avoid all that

Comment: @Seth: Better yet, `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: @benvoigt: i am new to c++. do you mean i need to overload the '=' operator? also i thought when we do objA = objB, everything is copied (here the bits pointer will be copied). Is that correct?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Record class is a library to me and hence I cannot change it!

Comment: @Seth: No, I mean `class Record { std::vector<char> bits; /* ... */ };`  A non-copyable, non-moveable object can't be contained in `std::vector`, and `Record` seems like it doesn't implement those properly.

Comment: @aakash: Show the constructor and destructor bodies then.  But it may be so bad you need to throw it away completely.  And you're right that `objA = objB` will copy everything including the `bits` pointer... after that you have two `bits` pointers pointing to the same memory.

Comment: @BenVoigt: the constructor and destructor are like this.
     Record :: Record () {
        bits = NULL;
     }

     Record :: ~Record () {
         if (bits != NULL) {
                 delete [] bits;
         }
         bits = NULL;
     }

Comment: @aakash: So, if you copy a `Record` (copying the `bits` pointer), they both will call `delete[]` with the same pointer.  See a problem?

Comment: @BenVoigt: oh!!! damn! yes i got the problem. thanks! i will overload the '=' operator then to solve this problem!
thanks to you too, Seth!

Comment: @aakash: You can't overload `operator=` outside the class, it MUST be a member function.  And you said you can't change `class Record`...

Comment: oooh, as i mentioned earlier, sorry i am new to c++ (and OOPS)! any ideas how can resize the array, since overloading cannot be done?

Comment: @aakash: I think you're stuck using `GetBits` on the old copy, and `SetBits` on the new one.  This `class Record` library is really horrible, and if there's any way you can get rid of it, I would.

Comment: @BenVoigt: there are actually 6-7 more functions of the Record class which are extremely useful. No problem, I will use GetBits() and SetBits() as suggested by you. I am not concerned about efficiency right now. thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: Oh, now I see that Seth was suggest that you hold `Record` via a pointer.  That would allow you to move it from one vector to another without actually copying it.  Pretty good idea that.