# How to correctly manage resources with move semantics?

Tags: c++, move, c++14, move-semantics

```
struct foo{
  int* i;
  foo(): i(new int(42)){}
  foo(const foo&) = delete;
  foo(foo&&) = default;
  ~foo(){
    std::cout << "destructor: i" << std::endl;
    delete(i);
  }
};
int main()
{
  foo f;
  auto sp_f = std::make_shared<foo>(std::move(f));
}
```

This is bad because it seems that the destructor of `f` will be called once it moves into the `shared_ptr`. The `shared_ptr` will have a deleted pointer and will delete it after it goes out of scope, which means the pointer will be deleted two times.

How do I avoid this problem?

Comment: Don't default the move constructor?

Comment: Yeah, actually define the move ctor and swap pointers, e.g. That or simply use something which has move semantics defined for it already, like `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Instead of a raw array, just use a `std::vector`. There. All OK. The key to managing resources in C++, is to **use the standard resource managers**. At least as far as possible.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I don't see a raw array here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to actually implement the rule of five?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5976459/3425536)

Comment: @zenith: maybe your eyes were fooled by the unconventional naming. the member `i` points to a raw array. XXX oh, it's my eyes fooled by unconventional everything: it's a `new` of a single `int`. very silly.

Comment: well, the solution then is pretty simple, namely to use an `int` instead of `int*`.

Comment: In this case you could just use `unique_ptr<int> i` and the Rule of Zero.  You can also use `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter, if the resource requires other release code.  It's good to avoid reinventing the wheel !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define the move constructor to prevent deletion from the moved-from object:

```
foo(foo&& f): i(f.i) {
  f.i = nullptr;
}
```

Now when to destructor of the old object is run, it won't delete the `i`, since deleting a null pointer is a no-op.

You should also define a move assignment operator and delete the copy assignment operator too.

Comment: What if my use case wasn't so trivial? What if I would need to call `delete_something(some_handle)`  and there would be no "noop" for some default value and calling it two times would be a problem?

Comment: You could always fall back to keeping a boolean flag to mark whether to clean the resource or not.

Comment: @MaikKlein I didn't quite understand. Can you provide a more elaborate example, possibly in the original question?

Comment: `class foo` could have a member `bool shouldDestroy` which would be checked at destruction time. If it is `true`, destroy the resource.

Answer (score 6):

The [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) is really the rule of five now. If you have a class that can be moved from, you should define the move semantics yourself (plus the copy, destructor, etc).

As to how to do that, to quote [cppreference's page on `std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move), *"... objects that have been moved from are placed in a valid but unspecified state."* The unspecified state is typically what the object would look like if it had been default initialized, or what would happen if the objects had `swap` called on them.

A straightforward way is, as @zenith has answered, is to have the move constructor (or assignment operator) set the original pointer to `nullptr`. This way the data isn't freed, and the original object is still in a valid state.

Another common idiom is, as mentioned, to use `swap`. If a class needs its own copy and move semantics, a `swap` method would be handy as well. The move constructor would delegate initialization to the default constructor, and then call the `swap` method. In a move assignment operator, just call `swap`. The object being moved into will get the resources, and the other object's destructor will free the original ones.

It would usually look like this:

```
struct Foo
{
    void* resource; //managed resource
    Foo() : resource(nullptr) {} //default construct with NULL resource
    Foo(Foo&& rhs) : Foo() //set to default value initially
    {
        this->swap(rhs); //now this has ownership, rhs has NULL
    }
    ~Foo()
    {
        delete resource;
    }
    Foo& operator= (Foo&& rhs)
    {
        this->swap(rhs); //this has ownership, rhs has previous resource
    }
    void swap(Foo& rhs) //basic swap operation
    {
        std::swap(resource, rhs.resource); //thanks @M.M
    }
};
```

Comment: Instead of the three-line swap, you can write `std::swap(resource, rhs.resource);`