# Error reading characters of string C++

Tags: c++, string, char

I am trying to store a value from a

```
vector<vector<string>> data;
```

into a const char* variable - declared in the .h file - in this way:

```
heightmapName = data[0][1].c_str();
```

When I debug the program I notice that the variable `heightmapName` return this

```
heightmapName 0xcdcdcdcd <Error reading characters of string.>  const char *
```

However, if I declare a new `const char*` and initialize it like this:

```
    const char* what = data[0][1].c_str();
    heightmapName = data[0][1].c_str();
```

`what` variable store the data just fine, while `heightmapName`doesn't.

This is the function:

```
void Configuration::fileParser(string fileName)
{
    vector<vector<string>> data;
    string line;
    string delimiter = " ";
    ifstream ss(fileName);
    if (ss)
    {
        while (getline(ss, line))
        {
            vector<string> dataLine;
            string token = line.substr(0, line.find(delimiter));
            string value = line.substr(line.find(delimiter) +1);
            dataLine.push_back(token);
            dataLine.push_back(value);
            data.push_back(dataLine);
        }
        ss.close();
    }
    //storeData(data);
    const char* ahah = data[0][1].c_str();
    heightmapName =    data[0][1].c_str();
}
```

Why is this happening? and how can I solve this?

ps. I am using visual studio 2017

Comment: 0xcdcdcdcd ..  Looks like uninitialized heap memory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations

Comment: Please post a [mcve],  No one knows how, when, or where `data` is initialized, used, filled with data, etc.

Comment: I edited the question with the code of the function.

Comment: `heightmapName` is undefined. It has no type. This code is not complete and probably won't compile. Is it a field within the `Configuration` class?

Comment: What is `heightmapName` declared as? If it is a `char*`, why is it not a `std::string` instead? Also, you are not checking if `data` is empty (because the file could not be opened, or the file is empty) before accessing `data[0]`. The vector's `operator[]` does not do any bounds checking (its `at()` method does)

Comment: It is a const char*. It's not here because declared in the .h file

Comment: Also, you posted a member function of a class.  If that is not a static member function, and if that `Configuration` object is not valid, no operations that you will do on it will be valid.  You need to show us a [mcve], not a snippet from a class.

Comment: @Steve `const char*` is not a const pointer, like you are thinking. It is a *non-const* pointer to a const `char`. So it can be reassigned to point at a different address, you just can't modify data through it. A const pointer would be like `char* const` (or `const char* const`) instead. Placement of `const` matters.

Comment: There are multiple things wrong with this code, with the most prominent one being a lack of error checking.  1) What if that line doesn't have a space?   You will then wind up using `std::string::npos` as the start of the `value` string.  2) What if there are no items in `data` when all is said and done?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know, but as the .txt file I am reading from is written by me and contains only one line, I was trying to focus on this problem first.

Comment: Reducing to a minimal complete example would probably show the problem...it has been suggested twice.  If I try assigning the value of `c_str` to a `const char *` it works fine.

Comment: @matt, there is enough info there to see the problem.  It's never going to work as-is.

Comment: @Swagging The moral of this whole story is stop using `const char *` when `std::string` is what you want.  If a function requires a `const char *`, use the `c_str()` function *directly* instead of storing the return value in your own `const char *`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Even that won't work unless you know that the result of c_str() won't be used after the string has changed or become released.

Comment: @Matt: Swagging did actually produce a gist which "worked", but had the undefined behaviour of showing the string instead of the access violation, as he was using data after the lifetime had ended. (That gist was removed, for some reason)

Comment: @Arafangion -- I understand, but my point is that storing the return of `c_str()` in your own `const char *`  member variable (at least in this case) is not necessary and just leads to problems such as this (Example: the `std::string` changes or is destroyed).   If `heightMapName` were `std::string`, probably none of these issues would have occurred.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Sure, that's a reasonable style guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of the problem or implementation, assuming that the type of `heightmapName` is indeed `const char *`, that's not going to work.

The lifetime of the `data` is bound by the fileParser lifetime.  See [What is std::string::c_str() lifetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456359/what-is-stdstringc-str-lifetime)

Therefore, at the end of that function, the data pointed to by `data[0][1].c_str()` will become invalid.

Consider copying the data if required. Or make heightmapName an std::string.

(Additional tips: If it's a pointer, consider applying the Rule Of Five: [How to actually implement the rule of five?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976459/how-to-actually-implement-the-rule-of-five) - another reason to avoid manual memory management)

In general, I avoid raw pointers in C++ classes by using smart pointers, or structures (such as std::string) that manages memory for me, this means I do not need to worry about the rule of 3 or rule of 5 as I won't need to manually manage those resources.

update: You mentioned that it "works" for you in a (now removed) gist.

Accessing memory like that after the lifetime has ended is undefined.  One behaviour could very well be that it magically "works".  Most likely, that memory just hasn't been overwritten yet.