# Implementing a resource handling class with move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I am trying to learn move semantics in modern C++.
It is my understanding that this construct is useful when designing a class which manages a resource.
I tried to experiment with this by building a very simple wrapper around C-style arrays, as follows.

```cpp
// A wrapper around int[] to practice with the rule of three/five
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>


class Vector {
public:
    Vector(const std::size_t n) : size_(n), data_(new int[n]) {
    std::cout << "called constructor" << std::endl; }
    ~Vector() { delete[] data_;
    std::cout << "called destructor" << std::endl; }
    Vector(const Vector&);
    Vector& operator=(Vector);
    friend void swap(Vector&, Vector&);
    std::size_t size() { return size_; }
    int& operator[](std::size_t i) { if (i >= size_) throw "out of bounds"; return data_[i]; }
    int operator[](std::size_t i) const { if (i >= size_) throw "out of bounds"; return data_[i]; }
    // move constructor
    Vector(Vector&& v);
    // move assignment not needed (see current copy assignment)
    //Vector& operator=(Vector&&);
private:
    std::size_t size_;
    int* data_;
};


void swap(Vector& a, Vector& b) {
    std::swap(a.size_, b.size_);
    std::swap(a.data_, b.data_);
}


Vector::Vector(const Vector& v) :
  size_(v.size_),
  data_(new int[v.size_])
{
    std::copy(v.data_, v.data_ + v.size_, data_);
    std::cout << "called copy constructor" << std::endl;
}


Vector::Vector(Vector&& v) :
  Vector(v.size_)
{
    swap(*this, v);
    std::cout << "called move constructor" << std::endl;
}


Vector& Vector::operator=(Vector v) {
    std::cout << "called copy assignement" << std::endl;
    swap(*this, v);
    return *this;
}


int main() {
    Vector a(2);
    Vector b(6);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < b.size(); ++i) {
        b[i] = static_cast<int>(i);
    }
    a = b;
    Vector c(b);
    Vector d(Vector(3));
}
```

I would expect that the last line of code, namely `Vector d(Vector(3))` would call the move constructor, as I initialise d with an rvalue (or at least I think this is what I am trying to do here).

However, this is the output when executing the program:

```
called constructor
called constructor
called copy constructor
called copy assignement
called destructor
called copy constructor
called constructor
called destructor
called destructor
called destructor
called destructor
```

It seems that the code is never calling the move constructor.
Why is this happening? How can I change my code so that it takes advantage of the move constructor?

I also tried changing the implementation of the move constructor as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5976829/9176725), namely:

```cpp
Vector::Vector(Vector&& v) :
  size_(std::move(v.size_)),
  data_(std::move(v.data_))
{
    v.size_ = 0;
    v.data_ = nullptr;
    std::cout << "called move constructor" << std::endl;
}
```

But still the move constructor is not used.

Comment: `Vector d(std::move(a));` would use the move constructor. I believe the compiler is optimizing `Vector d(Vector(3))` to be the same as `Vector d(3)` to avoid constructing a temporary and then moving it.

Comment: @JamesAdkison compiling with -O0 does not change the output (I'm using the GNU compiler). Is there a way to disable the optimisation?

Comment: @walnut thanks. Apart from this optimisation I was unaware of, are both my attempted move constructors fine? Is one of the two preferable over the other?

Comment: @J.D. The second one is a bit convoluted and the first one does too much work. It allocates in the delegated constructor (`Vector(v.size_)`), while it probably just should call a default-constructor (that you are currently lacking) to set the members to `nullptr`/`0`. Then you could also make it, the default-constructor and the `swap` function `noexcept` (assuming the `cout`'s don't stay there).

Comment: I'm not sure how to disable it. Why would you want to disable it? A quick search provided the following info which may be applicable: "GCC provides the ‑fno‑elide‑constructors option to disable copy-elision"

Comment: @JamesAdkison this flag works, thanks. I think for people who are learning C++ it could be useful to have the compiler generate an executable that is as close as possible to what we write in the source. I also realise that C++ is very much concerned with performance, so it is better to get accustomed to the compiler doing aggressive optimisation even with the -O0 flag.

I also find it strange that compiling the code with `Vector d(std::move(Vector(3))); `with the flag -Wpessimizing-move does not produce any warning that we are missing out an optimisation opportunity.