# How does wrapping a pointer work with rvalue references?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, rvalue-reference

std::shared_ptr::operator* returns by lvalue reference, and the answer given on overloading pointer like operations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719) says that the convention is to return by lvalue reference. However, when I'm using the following code, I get error C2664: 'AdjacencyList::addVertex' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'AdjacencyList::vertex_type' to 'AdjacencyList::vertex_type &&': You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference:

```
std::shared_ptr<vertex_type> AdjacencyList::addVertex(vertex_type&& v)
{
    auto existingVertex(findVertex(v));

    if (!existingVertex.isValid())
    {
        existingVertex = std::make_shared<vertex_type>(std::forward<vertex_type>(v))
        m_vertices.push_back(existingVertex);
    }

    return existingVertex;
};

AdjacencyList minimumSpanningTree;
// startVertex is a shared_ptr to a vertex returned from a previous call of addVertex
// on another AdjacencyList object
const auto mstStartVertex(minimumSpanningTree.addVertex(*startVertex));
```

Should I provide AdjacencyList::addVertex(const vertex_type& v) or change the code at the bottom of the above block to make a copy of the vertex before passing to addVertex?

```
AdjacencyList minimumSpanningTree;
Vertex s(*startVertex);
const auto mstStartVertex(minimumSpanningTree.addVertex(std::move(s)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient approach in terms of redundant copies is to provide rvalue and const reference overloads:

```
std::shared_ptr<vertex_type> AdjacencyList::addVertex(vertex_type&&);
std::shared_ptr<vertex_type> AdjacencyList::addVertex(const vertex_type&);
```

To eliminate the redundant code, you can forward to a template method or to a concrete method taking a `bool` flag and performing `const_cast` as appropriate.

If the overhead of copying the `Vertex` object is minimal compared to the cost of increased code, and if the `if` block is usually or often entered, then the redundant copy will make your code clearer.  Your second suggested call will work better if you just create a prvalue temporary that doesn't need to be moved:

```
const auto mstStartVertex(minimumSpanningTree.addVertex(Vertex{*startVertex}));
```

However in that case you might as well create the temporary in the call itself, by providing a single value overload ([How to reduce redundant code when adding new c++0x rvalue reference operator overloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696156/how-to-reduce-redundant-code-when-adding-new-c0x-rvalue-reference-operator-ove?rq=1)):

```
std::shared_ptr<vertex_type> AdjacencyList::addVertex(vertex_type);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would think that you should return a copy from your `operator*`, as the sematics of the `std::weak_ptr` suggest that you can not guarantee that a returned reference would stay valid. Since the returned copy is then given to a function which can move it somewhere else, it should also be efficient enough, since `addVertex` looks like it would require a copy anyways, i.e., if you *would* create an overload of `addVertex`, it will create a copy of the passed const reference internally, would it?

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily make a copy of the vertex; currently I look to see if the same vertex has already been added and if it has I do nothing. In most cases, it would copy though.

Comment: After your update, I'm not sure if I understand the need for the `weak_ptr` or the wrapper. Why don't you just return a `std::shared_ptr<vertex_type>`?

Comment: If the AdjacencyList goes out of scope or the vertex gets deleted  but someone is holding onto a vertex, I don't want to keep the vertex information around. The best example, though not relevant to my particular use case I can think of is scheduling pathfinding for multiple agents running across multiple frames in a game with a dynamic navigation graph. Maybe storing unique_ptr in AdjacencyList and returning an index would be better?

Comment: I think you make the wrong method responsible for this. Return a `std::shared_ptr` and let the caller decide if he wants to use it directly or if he want to store it. The caller should then store a `weak_ptr` if it is possible that the pointer-to object becomes invalid and if the caller could handle the situation of `.lock()` returning empty.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable way to go. Since std::shared_ptr::operator* still returns by reference, I've edited the question a bit to use shared_ptr specifically.